# jwt authentication login page with email and password

Tags: vue.js, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, nuxt.js

I'm trying to do a JWT authentication to a distinct API.

As @nuxtjs/auth-next doesn't seem to be up to date and as I read it was possible to use the new global method fetch in Nuxt 3 instead of @nuxtjs/axios (not up to date also), I thought it won't be too hard to code the authentication myself! But it stays a mystery to me and I only found documentation on Vue project (using Pinia to keep user logged in) and I'm a bit at a lost.

What I would like to achieve:

a login page with email and password, login request send to API (edit: done!)
get JWT token and user info from API (edit: done!) and store both (to keep user logged even if a page is refresh)
set the JWT token globally to header $fetch requests (?) so I don't have to add it to each request
don't allow access to other pages if user is not logged in
Any help on this?

Comment: Persistency for the token and have some global middleware is the way to go.

Comment: @2033_Shivam Kumar please share the code u tried